# FastAPI dependency injection - fail on first?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am attempting to create a "authorizer dependecy" for usine in FastAPI that accepts a `scope` parameter, which then checks a given auth token and if this user has access to a `resource` specified as a path parameter.

The problem is the way (and in which order, if any) FastAPI seems to evaluate these depedencies.

For this case, I would find it most ideal if the path parameter in the *path operation function* (`resource_id`) would be evaluated first and raise an exception and immediately "abort" if the user attempted to access an invalid resource path.

I guess it's not surprising that the  *path operation decorator* dependency is evaluated first, however, so I've also repeated the same path parameter validation in this one (which is also needed for permission checking against the resource).

The thing I *am* more surprised about, is that *both* of them are evaluated and included in a list of validation errors. Wouldn't it give more sense if it raised a single exception on the first dependency which not fulfilled (not continue evaluating *all* of them)?

Since the `authorize` dependecy not always require a specified `resource_id`, I've also attempted to make this an optional, but since this dependecy is evaluated first, it still attempts to authroize the user agianst a (possible) invalid `resource_id`.

Is there any way to instruct fastapi to fail on first "failed" dependecy, control it's order, or any better designs to solve this problem?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, status, Path
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials

app = FastAPI()

http_bearer = HTTPBearer(scheme_name="Token")

def authorize(scope: str):
    def _check_permission(
        resource_id: str, # = Path(None, regex=r"^[0-9a-f-]+$"),
        authorization: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(http_bearer),
    ):
        # check credentials and permission `scope` on `resource_id`
        return True
    return _check_permission


@app.get(
    "/{resource_id}",
    dependencies=[Depends(authorize("read"))],
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
)
def get_resource(
    resource_id: str = Path(..., regex=r"^[0-9a-f-]+$"),
):
    return f"access granted: {resource_id}"
```

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "resource_id"
      ],
      "msg": "string does not match regex \"^[0-9a-f-]+$\"",
      "type": "value_error.str.regex",
      "ctx": {
        "pattern": "^[0-9a-f-]+$"
      }
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "resource_id"
      ],
      "msg": "string does not match regex \"^[0-9a-f-]+$\"",
      "type": "value_error.str.regex",
      "ctx": {
        "pattern": "^[0-9a-f-]+$"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a dependency to the dependency?

Comment: @Isabi Yes, I've tried reusing the same `Path` dependency in my `authorize` dependecy, i.e. `resource_id: str = Path(None, regex=r"^[0-9a-f-]+$")`

Comment: Do you raise an HTTPException in the authorize function?